# What is an openstack port?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to map the notion of an openstack port to an IP abstraction. In the openstack documentation I see :

"A port is a connection point for attaching a single device, such as the NIC of a server, to a network. The port also describes the associated network configuration, such as the MAC and IP addresses to be used on that port."

So I assume a port must correspond to an IP interface (which in turn can map to a bridge, an ethernet interface or to one end of a veth link).

Is this a correct assumption? I am trying to figure out what IP abstraction maps to a loadbalancer port and I can't yet find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (hopefully of help to others):

An openstack port corresponds to an ovs (or linnuxbridge) port that connects you up to a virtual network. A prefix of the port ID is used as a bridge name. You can create a port to a network and add it to a router.